# Read inner and outer radius of arc - d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, transform

I'm working on a project which deals with visual representation of large relational data. We are using pie chart to display the data components(In order). Due to lack of space we are displaying only 10 at a time.

**Consider the following example:**

Assume that I have 100 data components, out of which I'll display only 10 at a given point of time. The logic i'm using is, I'm setting start and end angle to 0(Zero) for other 90 components. Where in for those 10 components i'm calculation the start and end angle as below-

```
var angle = 360;
var count = 10;
if(data.length > count) angle = angle/count; //data is array of data component names
else angle = angle/data.length;

//Initially I'll be displaying first ten components
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var startAngle = i * angle;
    var endAngle = startAngle + angle;
    var pi = = Math.PI/180;

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(innerRadius) //dynamic value, calculated based on available space
        .outerRadius(outerRadius) //dynamic value, calculated based on available space
        .startAngle((startAngle)*pi)
        .endAngle((endAngle)*pi);

    //Hiding rest of the data components
    if(i >= count){
        arc.startAngle(0);
        arc.endAngle(0);
    }

    arcGroup.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("stroke", "#2E2E2E")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("fill","gold");

    var text = arcGroup.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + arc.centroid() + ")")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-family","noto_sansregular")
        .attr("font-size", 40)
        .attr("font-weight","Bold")
        .attr("fill", "#000000")
        .attr("y",0)
        .style("visibility", "visible")
        .text(data[i]);

    //Hiding text of hidden arcs
    if(i >= count) text.style("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

Then if user wants to see the rest of the components, i'm providing two buttons to rotate (clock or anti-clock) the content.

If current view is -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

On rotate by one cell clockwise, resulting view should be -> 100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

In this case I need to hide component '10' and display component '100', and shift rest of the cells. To achieve this i just need to change the start and end angles of the arcs. I can create new arc object with calculated angles.

**The problem here is I don't know how to get the inner and outer radius of the arc, which are dynamically created.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like that,

```
...
arcGroup.append("path")
    .filter(function(d) { 
        // You're Not restricted to the "filter" function
        var innerRadius = d.innerRadius()(d);
        var outerRadius = d.outerRadius()(d);
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it is possible to retrieve the `innerRadius` and `outerRadius` from the `d` attribute of the `path` elements, but it will require parsing the DSL and will be tedious. These values are not stored *nicely* on the elements itself by d3.

Hence, it would be better if you recompute the `innerRadius` and `outerRadius` while updating the elements:

```
function showFromIdx(firstIndex) {
  argGroup.selectAll('path')
    .data( d3.range(data.length)
             .map(function (d) { 
                return (d - firstIndex + data.length) % data.length; 
              })
    )
    .attr('d', function (d) {
      // You will have to calculate the radii again here.
      var innerRadius = foo(d), outerRadius = bar(d);
      return d3.svg.arc()
              .startAngle(i < count ? i * angle : 0)
              .endAngle(i < count ? (i + 1) * angle : 0)
              .innerRadius(innerRadius)
              .outerRadius(outerRadius)(d);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now i'm storing inner and outer radius in a variable so I can reuse it. But now i'm facing some other issue - when the transformation occurs, it rotates but it looks like re-rendering from a dot to arc. As i'm not changing the inner and outer radius, its just the start and end angle. How can I just set only start and end angle for transformation? I saw few examples on attrTween, but that needs dataSet, which i'm not using and don't want to use as I need control (assigning unique id, color, pointer etc for each pie component) over each pie component

Answer (score 1):

Here are several functions that I wrote to get inner and outer radiuses of arcs created using d3. Please tell me if you find mistakes in code.

```
function getInnerRadiusFromArc(arc) {
  var numbersInPattern = _getArcNumbers(arc);

  // Possibly, that's sector, so it starts from 0.
  // Or maybe that's something else.
  if (numbersInPattern.length < 4) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Getting minimum from the array.
  var innerRadius = Math.min.apply(null, numbersInPattern);

  return innerRadius;
}

function getOuterRadiusFromArc(arc) {
  var numbersInPattern = _getArcNumbers(arc);

  // Getting maximum from the array.
  var outerRadius = Math.max.apply(null, numbersInPattern);

  return outerRadius;
}

function _getArcNumbers(arc) {
  // Path description parameter, containing necessary data.
  var pathDescription = arc.getAttribute("d");

  // We need to get all patterns like A<number>,<number>.
  // RegExp source:
  // http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html
  const numberRegExp = /[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?/g;
  var arcPattern = new RegExp("A" + numberRegExp.source + "," + numberRegExp.source, "g");
  var arcParameters = pathDescription.match(arcPattern);

  var numbersInPattern = [];

  // We get all the numbers from array ["A<number>,<number>", "A<number>,<number>", ...].
  for (let parameterIndex = 0; parameterIndex < arcParameters.length; parameterIndex++) {
    let parameter = arcParameters[parameterIndex];

    let numbers = parameter.match(numberRegExp);

    if (numbers !== null) {
      numbersInPattern = numbersInPattern.concat(numbers);
    }
  }

  // Transform strings in our array to numbers.
  numbersInPattern = numbersInPattern.map(function (numberString) {
    return parseFloat(numberString);
  });

  return numbersInPattern;
}
```